# CSS Selectors is JavaFX setStyle() method

Tags: css, listview, javafx, styling

There is an option to bind CSS files to add style to JavaFX components.
But I want to change some properties dynamically in code.
There is a setStyle() method but there is not enough documentation available on using it.

I want to change the hover color from the setStyle() method instead of the .css file.

Here is the code for the .css file

```
.list-cell:filled:hover 
{
   -fx-background-color: #0093ff;
   -fx-text-fill: white; 
}
```

### [image: JavaFX ListView]

and I want to change the hover color from the setStyle() method dynamically like this:

```
noteListView.setStyle(
                    ":filled:hover{" +
                    "-fx-background-color: #65ffb0;" +
                    "-fx-text-fill: white;" +
                    "}");
```

But this does not work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Javadoc explains why it doesn't work:

`Note that, like the HTML style attribute, this variable contains style properties and values and not the selector portion of a style rule.`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try something like that, I used it to change the color of a specific serie on a chart which be selected from a tableview.

```js
table.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener( (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> changeId(oldValue, newValue));


    public void changeId(Number oldV, Number newV){
     if(oldV.intValue() != -1){
      lineChart.getData().get(oldV.intValue()).getNode().setId("serie-unselect");
     }
     if(newV.intValue() != -1){
      lineChart.getData().get(newV.intValue()).getNode().setId("serie-select");
     }
    }
```

Then in the css file, you add #serie-select{} and #serie-unselect{} with good options.